# Table set maximal row's in tr

Tags: html, css, modx

In modx i try to create table with getResources, but i have trouble...

everybody who read this, don't care, it's not a pure modx question, it's more html question

for example my call is:

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`[[*id]]` &level=`1` &where=`{"isfolder":"1"}` &rowTpl=`menuRowMiddle` &outerTpl=`menuOuterMiddle`]]
```

and my templates:
outer:

```
<td width="50%" valign="top">
    <div style="padding: 5 0 5 0;">
        <a style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding: 10 0 10 0; text-decoration: none;" href="[[+wf.link]]" [[+wf.attributes]]><span>[[+wf.linktext]]</span>[[+wf.wrapper]]</a>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 10px;"></div>
</td>
```

row:

```
<td width="50%" valign="top">
    <div style="padding: 5 0 5 0;">
        <a style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding: 10 0 10 0; text-decoration: none;" href="[[+wf.link]]" [[+wf.attributes]]><span>[[+wf.linktext]]</span>[[+wf.wrapper]]</a>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 10px;"></div>
</td>
```

but i have one tr, and huge count of td's

BUT!   how to limit this td - to one in row, and such tr must be some count, not one....

can i do this with pure html or not?   (maybe css?)

Comment: Please provide the markup of your intended result as it's unclear what you're asking for. Remove the inline styles as they just clutter the code (and they are bad practice - get them into a stylesheet).

Comment: @okyanet sa result i need <table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table> in such way, maximal two td's in one tr

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to output this:

```
<tr>    
<td valign="top">
    <div style="padding: 5 0 5 0;">
        <a style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding: 10 0 10 0; text-decoration: none;" href="[[+wf.link]]" [[+wf.attributes]]><span>[[+wf.linktext]]</span>[[+wf.wrapper]]</a>
        </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 10px;"></div>
</td>
</tr>
```

and you should be ok

Comment: then i have only one columnt, but need 2 )))\

Answer (score 0):

Wayfinder doesn't have an option of specifying alternating odd/nth chunks, so it's not possible to construct serverside. Your options would be to output it all in one row and use javascript to remodel the table into a structure you prefer, or change to use getResources if possible, where you can use it's `&tplFirst, &tpl, &tplOdd/&tpl_nN, &tplLast` parameters to build exactly what you need.

If you really want to use Wayfinder you could always modify it to enable the use of an alternating `&rowTpl` but that should really be a last resort.

Even using `:nth-child` CSS selectors to absolutely position the TD's would be more or less undoable in combination with wayfinder since you would really need a couple of classes to identify when you want to move the elements both vertical and horizontal.